# Android check if bluetooth exist on the device

Tags: android

Is there any way to check is a device has a bluetooth adapter or not?
I have a tablet that not has a bluetooth. So how can I handle that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add permission to Manifest

```
<manifest ... >
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
  ...
</manifest>
```

Code for Activity

```
BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
    //handle the case where device doesn't support Bluetooth
}
else
{
    //bluetooth supported
}
```

Comment: Be careful, on some devices this might crash due to NoClassDefNotFound for BluetoothManager

Answer (score 6):

For completeness, I think you can also do something like this:

```
getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)
```

And I presume this for normal bluetooth:

```
getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH)
```

Not sure if this is more optimal then requesting adapter thou.

Comment: Note getPackageManager() you can get by 2 way:
1) context.getPackageManager(); or
2) getActivity().getPackageManager()

Answer (score 2):

You can simply check if you can get its default `BluetoothAdapter` or not.

```
BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
    //handle the case where device doesn't support Bluetooth
}
else
{
    //bluetooth supported
}
```

Hope this helps.